# Nested loop through the different lists in R

Tags: r, arraylist, nested-loops

I have the 5 lists of length 10, `d1,...,d5`. 
for example the `d1` is :

```
> d1
[[1]]
 [1] -0.4470862 -7.2330362  2.0060165 -1.8135874 -6.3239906 -9.2819973 -4.5281328 -0.4646620 -3.6033140 -8.4078084

[[2]]
 [1]  0.8860549 -5.5916677  4.3382399 -5.6031842 -7.1132885  1.8388706  5.3161508 12.9872906 10.9063864 -2.7285185

[[3]]
 [1]  1.7715003 -5.3555033  6.7489209  8.6213950 -2.1861336  8.8199678  6.3897033 -8.7263417  0.4513869  3.7055572

[[4]]
 [1]  -6.4443679  -7.8786053   1.2553411  -9.4590218  -3.3743598 -14.6997473 -11.4365114  -0.3903306  -0.6343901   0.1218937

[[5]]
 [1]  -7.1302642  11.2561616   7.9592310  -0.9878423   0.2744908   2.2974143  -2.5867071  -9.6975011 -10.9544252   5.3961757

[[6]]
 [1] -12.4285771   1.9922676  -2.6495977   2.3891633  -4.0980340 -15.3845265  -4.8952363  -3.0497065  -0.6652166  -0.7398617

[[7]]
 [1]  -1.4175504 -11.3625955  -6.2915938  -7.5563334   0.7397468  -7.4810663  -1.2341943  -5.1838253   2.4293057   2.1604598

[[8]]
 [1]  -8.9740261  -3.8747773  -8.4827669  -2.6074740 -16.5657409  -0.6334476 -10.2824297 -13.6752398  -1.8896523   5.5975585

[[9]]
 [1]  -2.7644181  -4.4193104  -3.0591752 -11.0800374  -0.2166242   7.6568081  10.2937062   0.8078439  -5.6475922   0.1152055

[[10]]
 [1]  -4.2258527  -3.7496935  -7.4994027   2.4172585  -0.9224533   3.7842335  -5.0711585 -10.5714328  -1.4858401  -1.3034318
```

I want to compare the elements of these list with some constants, `c1,...,c5` and assign the result to another list. 
This is the code:

```
result<-list()
for(i in 1:10){for (j in 1:10)
  if (d1[[i]][j]>=c1 | d2[[i]][j]>=c2| d3[[i]][j]>=c3 | d4[[i]][j]>=c4| d5[[i]][j]>=c5) 
  { result[[i]][j]==TRUE}}
```

But I receive this result:

```
> result
list()
```

Please help me to modify the code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning anything with `{ result[[i]][j]==TRUE}}`. Don't you need `{ result[[i]][j]=TRUE}}` or `{ result[[i]][j] <- TRUE}}` ?

UPDATE: perhaps the first time your conditions hold is when i = 3 and j = 5 for example. An empty list does not contain anything yet, so it cannot assign something at the 3rd nested list and its 5th element. You could create the "target" list before and fill it with NAs, like this, and run your for loop afterwards:

`result <- list(rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10),rep(NA,10))`

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I checked `{ result[[i]][j] <- TRUE}}` but the same result.

Comment: It is created the list of `NA`s.

Comment: No, after running the whole code, a list of NA's is created with lengths equal to 10.

Comment: Could you dput your data?